# Spring-data-jpa: Thread-safe unique insert

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, thread-safety

I'm trying to emulate a distributed application with `parallelStream()`, writing on a db, where entry combinations should be unique. However, I've tried several options from `@Transactional` and `@Lock` but none seems to work.

Here is a part of the code, that should make the issue clear:

In `AtomicDbService`:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public TestEntity atomicInsert(TestEntity testEntity) {
    TestEntityParent testEntityParent = testEntityParentRepository
            .findByStringTwo(testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo())
            .orElseGet(() -> testEntityParentRepository.save(TestEntityParent.builder()
                    .stringTwo(testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo())
                    .build()));

    return testEnityRepository.findByStringAndTestEntityParentStringTwo(
            testEntity.getString(), testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo()
    ).orElseGet(() -> testEnityRepository
            .save(
                    TestEntity.builder()
                            .string(testEntity.getString())
                            .testEntityParent(testEntityParent)
                            .build()
            )
    );
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void testOperationsParallelStream() {

    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    list.parallelStream().forEach(lala -> atomicDbService.atomicInsert(testEntity));

    System.out.println(testEnityRepository.findAll());

}
```

As output I get e.g.:

```
[TestEntity(id=4, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=3, stringTwo=testTwo)), TestEntity(id=5, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=1, stringTwo=testTwo))]
```

But actually it should be only one result. More threads of course lead to exceptions.

Comment: You don't state which database you use. If that isolation mode works (or how it works) differs from database to database.

Comment: At the moment I do the test with embedded H2 (`runtime('com.h2database:h2')`. In production we use MySQL at present, but might switch in future.

Comment: It seems you want data-consistency at database level and not at application level, so this is not thread-safety. Thread-safety does not apply when you have several instances of your application (microservice) running. At database level, you would need to apply some form of locking: either pessimistic – you would need to lock a row or a table at the beginning of the transaction – or optimistic – you would define some constraints that would cause a rollback of your transaction if they are violated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I didn't mention it here, but the save method is annotated as pessimistic write. This however didn't change anything, and as far as I understood, `isolation.SERIALIZABLE` should do the same?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation isn't going to provide any application level thread safety. What you are seeing is a thread safety issue. With the UPSERT pattern you have created with `orElseGet` followed by a `save` you're going to need thread level protection in the application. The database won't know anything about this pattern since you're creating different rows in different transactions. Probably something like:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public TestEntity atomicInsert(TestEntity testEntity) {

synchronized(TestEntity.class) {
        TestEntityParent testEntityParent = testEntityParentRepository.findByStringTwo(testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo())
                .orElseGet(() -> testEntityParentRepository.save(TestEntityParent.builder()
                        .stringTwo(testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo())
                        .build()));

        return testEnityRepository.findByStringAndTestEntityParentStringTwo(
                testEntity.getString(), testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo()
        ).orElseGet(() -> testEnityRepository
                .save(
                        TestEntity.builder()
                                .string(testEntity.getString())
                                .testEntityParent(testEntityParent)
                                .build()
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean, I wouldn't have that issue, if say to services instead of two threads would do that work?

Comment: Ok, I've tried it, it worked for 4 threads, however more threads again lead to doubled entries. Could you give a short hint, what's gong on behind? Is it attempting to force serialized execution of the parallel threads?

Comment: Are you sure about your test data? In the response you posted TestEntitys 4 and 5 have different parent ids. That seems like it should be correct based on the logic you have there. You still need the synchronization so that the parent is only created once though.

Comment: You still would have the issue if two services were making the calls. They would most likely be in different threads. Especially if the services are invoked from controller calls as is normal.

Comment: Hmm, I am certainly not the first one trying to create distributed applications that insert into databases with spring. So I was hoping for some kind of standard solution.

Comment: The distribution isn't the problem. It is the get-or-create pattern for the parent and the child. Because you are creating both the parent and the child in a single transaction there is a potential race condition between your transactions where you could create a parent more than once. However, based on your response this call must be returning a different response testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo() for different invocations in your test code because you get two different parent ids in the output.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean? I added the test output to show what's going wrong. I expect only one row in each table. If I do things in a simple `foreach` (without `parallelStream`) my test output is: `[TestEntity(id=2, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=1, stringTwo=testTwo))]` . That is expected.

Comment: Using `synchronized` will not work in typical web applications, which will run in cluster mode with several instances. You have to find a solution at database level.